# Angular localize: a duplicated app for every language?

Tags: angular, localization, internationalization, angular-i18n, angular-localize

[Some years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46242346/string-resources-in-angular) I used [@ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for dealing with string replacement in my Angular application.

Now I need to internationalize my application and although @ngx-translate still seems to be the better choice I would give a chance* to the Angular i18n built-in capabilities.

I have read the [Angular i18n documentation](https://angular.io/guide/i18n) and it seems to be quite simple to have a translated version of an application (despite the use of XML instead of JSON!).

As the documentation states:

> due to the deployment complexities of i18n and the need to minimize rebuild time, the development server only supports localizing a single locale at a time

In addition I have to build a different app for every language, that results in having duplicated apps:

```
ng build --configuration=production,fr
ng build --configuration=production,es
ng build --configuration=production,it
ng build --configuration=production,de
```

Am I right? Shouldn't we have only one app and as many "message.xlf" files (or something similar) as languages that are loaded at runtime?

**I have read somewhere that the maintainer of ngx-translate believes that as soon as Angular “catches up”, his solution will be deprecated. In fact, he was hired by the Angular team to work on the I18n module; he states that the built-in solution is much more complex and bug-free. So, while ngx-translate is still being widely used, maybe we should think about transferring to the built-in module sooner or later*.

Comment: You care correct. You shouldn't use ngx-translate anymore but rather Transloco if you are not happy with the built-in solution. I just did a lot of research that went into this article if you want to read more: https://medium.com/dailyjs/maintaining-multi-language-angular-applications-26b74df8d085
It's possible to have only one application but the support is not all the way there. There are 3rd party libraries to aid you though.

Answer (score 0):

You're absolutely right, yes...

Using Angular's i18n mechanism requires you to make a separate build for each locale.

As an addition, I'd like to add that Netanel Basal (and a bunch of other developer) has made a (more modern?) replacement to ngx-translate (called transloco) - it can be found here: https://github.com/ngneat/transloco

Comment: And what about this: https://blog.angular.io/angular-localization-with-ivy-4d8becefb6aa